# setting a datetime in python to utcnow - 30

Tags: python

I am trying to set a datetime to now - a month using utcnow.

something like that :

```
newdate = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=utc) - 30
```

but ofcourse the - 30 wont work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `timedelta`:

```
newdate = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=utc) - datetime.timedelta(days=30)
```

Comment: Because of the datetime library even in Python3 has so many warning, I would use datetime.datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc) to get the non-naive datetime object.

Answer (score 2):

If you actually want a month (as opposed to just 30 days), use the [dateutil](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil) module:

```
import dateutil
now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=utc)
newdate = now - dateutil.relativedelta(months=1)
```